# position divs at top and bottom of containing div

Tags: html, css, position, css-float

I have a container div which has content that will sometimes need to be divided by `class="top"` and `class="bottom"`. Obviously there is no `float:top` or `float:bottom`, so what is the best way to achieve this with html/css alone?

Ex:

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="left">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/home.jpg" alt="salon home"></a>
        </div><!-- end left -->
        <div class="center">
            <a href="#" class="top"><img src="img/about.jpg" alt="about salon"></a>
            <a href="#" class="bottom"><img src="img/services.jpg" alt="salon service"></a>
        </div><!-- end center -->
        <div class="right">
            <a href="#" class="top"><img src="img/products.jpg" alt="salon products"></a>
            <a href="#" class="bottom"><img src="img/contact.jpg" alt="contact salon"></a>
        </div><!-- end right -->
    </div><!-- end content -->

#container .content {
    margin-top: 115px;
}

#container .content .left {
    float: left;
    width: 307px;
}

#container .content .center {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 19px;
    width: 307px;
}

#container .content .right {
    float: right;
    width: 307px;
}
```

ETA - FIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/FaTxw/2/

Comment: Absolute positioning?

Comment: @j08691 that would disable `float:right` and `float:left`, no?

Comment: Are you trying to force `<a href="#" class="top">` to the top, and `<a href="#" class="bottom">` to the bottom?  It's pretty difficult to determine the exact results you're wanting from your question.

Comment: @Axel Yes, that's exactly what I'm wanting to do/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a few easy steps.

1) Add relative positioning to the parent containers:

```
 #container .content .left,
 #container .content .center,
 #container .content .right { 
    position: relative;
 }
```

2) Set the child elements to absolute positioning.

```
#container .content .top,
#container .content .bottom {
   position: absolute;
}
```

3) Set the elements to top and bottom positions.

```
#container .content .top {
   top: 0;
}

#container .content .bottom {
   bottom: 0;
}
```

4) Set the height of all parent containers to 100%

```
html, body, #container, .content, .left, .right, .center {
    height: 100%;
}
```

5) Set a min-height on the container so the top and bottom children won't overlap.

```
#container {
    min-height: 349px;
}
```

See a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/FaTxw/3/

Comment: This seems to be very much along the right lines, however after implementing the above code, the elements that I have applied `.top` and `.bottom` to are stuck at the very top of the page. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/FaTxw/

Comment: I've updated my answer with a few more steps.  You need to set the height on the containers so the positions will be correct.  I've included an update of your JSfiddle as a working example.