# CSS : Clamp divs to top and bottom in an inline container

Tags: html, css

**[SOLVED]**

[Here's the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zGB2L/1/)

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="column">
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="top">
                TOP
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                BOTTOM
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

#container .content .column {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#container .content .top,
#container .content .bottom {
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #AAA;
}

#container .content .top {
   top: 0;
}

#container .content .bottom {
   bottom: 0;
}

#container {
    min-height: 349px;
}
```

I have three inline columns, the left and right ones have the same dynamic height (they contain generated tables with a variable number of rows)
I want the middle column to have the same height as its neighbours and I want his TOP div to clamp to the top and BOTTOM div to clamp to the bottom.

I've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978495/position-divs-at-top-and-bottom-of-containing-div) but can't manage to make it work.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot !

**EDIT**
Using Sowmya's solution :
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zGB2L/5/)

```
<div id="container">
    <div style="position: relative;">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="column">
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="top">
                TOP
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                BOTTOM
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

#container .content .column {
    display:table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#container .content .top,
#container .content .bottom {
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #AAA;
}

#container .content .top {
   top: 0;
}

#container .content .bottom {
   bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: And if you want the columns to always be same height dispite their content, use @Sowmya's solution

Comment: @PellePenna That won't work on Firefox..

Comment: Why will it not work on Firefox?

Comment: @PellePenna As I said http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985220/css-clamp-divs-to-top-and-bottom-in-an-inline-container/21985345#comment33316824_21985325

Comment: Yes, your're right .. still, if he needs a "equal column height" solution he need something different than just changing `vertical-align` + `min-height` and thats why a display-table/cell solution will work though it has to be properly set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `display:table-cell;` to `.column`

```
#container .content .column {
    position: relative;
    display:table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/vigupeke/3/)**

Comment: It will break the layout.. as Firefox doesn't respect `position: relative;` on element using `display: table-cell;`

Comment: Actually Firefox does respect relative, but you need to set `display: inline-block;`

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Indeed it doesn't work on firefox. In order to combine position:relative, with display:table-cell you have to wrap the content in another div. I've updated my question with the new code